# Does putting pandan leaves' stems in water prolong its freshness?

Tags: storage-method, herbs

I live in a tropical area where *Pandanus amarylliforius* is a common cooking ingredient, usually for making rice smell better, or baked into bread. We have a pandan plant in our garden, usually we harvest it when its the right size to be a rice aromatic but then we'd have to keep it fresh. Would leaving the stem in water suffice?